Why aren't two independent loops in LabView within case structures running simultaneously?
In LabView, I have a situation where I am trying to have two processes (loops) each within a case structure controlled by a Boolean control start when each respective button is pressed. However, if I press one and try to press another right after, the second process won't start until the first one finishes. Here I posted a picture is a simplified example with the same problem.

Most posts I have seen seem to just say that the loops are dependent on each other, which in my case they are not. I have tried adjusting the mechanical actions of the controls. I have also tried adjusting timers. Nothing seems to have helped, so if anyone knows the solution that would be greatly appreciated.

The value of the start buttons is read exactly once at the start of each iteration of the outer while loop. It is not constantly rechecked while the iteration still runs.

You have to separate the outer while loop, too. For the stop button, you can create a local variable for the button and use that in the second loop.
